# Adding a constant value to a column within a 2D numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with nd arrays which contain coordinate data for multiple contours in [x, y, z] space.

I am trying to add x, y, and z offsets to the lines based on other conditions. The offsets will be the same for any of the lines within the array.

Here is a sample array

```
arr= [[[0, 0, 0] 
       [0, 0, 0]]
      [[0, 0, 0]
       [0, 0, 0]]
      [[0, 0, 0]
       [0, 0, 0]]]
```

If I have xOffset = 1, and yOffset = 2, and zOffset = 0 how do I add it to the individal line it returns:

```
arr= [[[1, 2, 0] 
       [1, 2, 0]]
      [[1, 2, 0]
       [1, 2, 0]]
      [[1, 2, 0]
       [1, 2, 0]]]
```

I have tried using

```
arr[:][:][0] += xOffset
arr[:][:][1] += yOffset
arr[:][:][2] += zOffset
```

But it adds the offsets to every column, not just the x, y, z columns in the subarrays

Comment: `arr[:][:][0]` is just `arr[0]`.  `arr[:,:,0]` indexes the last dimension.

Comment: Before doing much more with `numpy`, spend some time with its intro documentation, including how to index multidimensional arrays.  Your use of a bare `[:]` comes from your imagination,  not any documented python ussge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create a temporary offset column as a 1D array and then add it into the corrected column, you should be able to do column arithmetic with numpy (It has been a moment since I've tried it myself)

This answer may also help you.

[Doing arithmetic with python array columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368746/doing-arithmetic-with-python-array-columns)